# Change Package version number of Windows Universal App for Windows Phone 8.1 app version while publishing

Tags: package, version, publish, windows-store

After migrating my app from Windows Phone 8.0 to Windows Universal App 8.1, I had problems with Package version number.

What I put in appxmanifest is 1.1.58.0.
[image: appxmanifest]

Creating App Package, I keep 1.1.58.0.
[image: Create App Package]

When I upload to the dashboard it shows a datetime based version: 2014.1124.1949.1685
[image: dashboard]

On the store it also shows datetime based version as well:
[image: store]

And finally in the app "About", it's showing the right version using Package to get the version.

```
string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}",
Package.Current.Id.Version.Major,
Package.Current.Id.Version.Minor,
Package.Current.Id.Version.Build);
```

[image]

My question is: How do I change the Package Version that shows on the Store?
I had no problems before Universal App.

Answer (score 7):

During the "Create App Packages" wizard, set the option for 'Generate app bundle' to Never. It will now pick up the version defined under the Packaging tab of the Package.appxmanifest file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer does not work for me, after I change "Generate app bundle" (pic 1 on question) to never, it changes back to always after the package is created, and it does not let me change it during the creation (pic 2 on question).

Comment: What if you selected "No" for "Do you want to build packages to upload to the Windows Phone Store?" ?

That's the screen between pic 1 and pic 2 in the question. You can still manually upload .appx file to the store (instead of the bundle). 

It should then pick up the version correctly from the manifest file.

Comment: When I choose No, I can't upload to store, it says: "The packages can be unsed only on Windows Phone Emulators or an unlocked phone.". Thanks for trying to help me anyway.

Comment: i don't like this answer, because it doesn't say WHY.  Why would I want to generate an app bundle?  Why would I not want to?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975357.aspx#Appx  Not sure why we can't select a verison number for app bundles.

Comment: This worked for me. But you can't update the package from Bundle version to APPX version (if you had been created the app with bundle). So you have to create another app based on APPX versioning if you don't want the default Bundle versioning.

Comment: this has worked for me, just make sur that you select Never in both the appxmanifest & when you create the app Package: http://i.imgur.com/FT9Ec0w.png